# Can anybody help me with these sentences?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I have read a book about prosecutors and justice and I am wondering what the following means.

> We maintained our right to argue for the twenty-year sentence, which we thought was just. We were merely giving up our ability to mandate such a sentence by requiring a plea to the mandatory minimum charge.

Please make it clear for me.

Comment: What *specifically* don't you understand?

Comment: Does "we were merely giving up our ability to mandate" mean that the prosecutors didn't make a request to a judge to give a centain penalty to the accused?

Comment: Ideally you should "edit" your question text to include that. Otherwise people might waste time explaining other aspects of the text that you don't need help with. But it's good that you *included* the preceding sentence, because that's part of the *context* that we ned to see.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the text is saying:

We kept the right to argue (in court) for the judge to impose a sentence (on the guilty person) of 20 years in prison.

We considered that this was a just sentence (for the crime concerned).

What we were conceding was just our ability to require a 20 year sentence (for the crime rather than a lesser sentence).

We conceded this by insisting (that the accused person) should plead (guilty) to the  minimum charge possible (that could be brought in the case).

(This principle can be illustrated when a person accused of murder agrees to plead guilty to the lesser charge of manslaughter. Or, in the USA, to a charge of second degree murder where first degree murder is alleged.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation 
I have one question.
Does " giving up our ability to mandate" means that  the prosecutors didn't make a request to a judge to give a centain penalty to the accused?

Comment: No, it means that they were surrendering their ability to require something;  not that they did not require it, they merely didn't need to if they didn't want to. The passage is written in legal language that would trouble most native English speakers.

Comment: I must admit I don't understand why the cited text says they ***required*** the defendant to cop for a lesser plea. Surely they ***permitted*** him to do that - something he'd have ***wanted*** to do, since he would otherwise face much more serious charges leading to prolonged incarceration.

Comment: It's been puzzling me too. The final part of the sentence is ambiguous. It's not clear to me whether **requiring a plea to the mandatory minimum charge** refers back to their ability or to mandating the sentence. It mean mean that they are giving up their ability to require such a plea rather than to mandate such a sentence?